# Installing and running Scapy on Windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, scapy

Here's the problem : I want to install Scapy for a personnal school project of mine and I can't seem to get it working...

I'm not familiar with Python at all so it could be the root of the problem but after installing all the required files from the site (http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows All of these) and adding the required directories to my PATH, I can't seem to run a Scapy terminal as a simple "scapy" in cmd.exe just returns me a "'Scapy' isn't recognized as an internal or external command, an executable or a command file".

Any idea what I did wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: After editing the PATH you need to restart your computer. If you have done that, can you run scapy by writing out the entire path to the exe?

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough (and I can't believe that I could be so stupid) Restarting my computer made it work, your answer was quick and spot on : thank you kind stranger, you definitely made my day !